# Quantum Mechanical Thinking

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, quantum-chemistry

I've just been wondering about how atoms and molecules can be quantum mechanically thought about, and I have a question.

It is often said that intermolecular bonding is purely "electrostatic". I hope what this means is that it is easier to consider molecules as point charges that are attracted, but in reality, there is some sort of orbital superposition, but the small distances between different charges within a molecule don't really matter. Is it correct to say that the essential physics is captured by considering the particles as classical Coulomb charges?

Comment: Wow... that's a textbook full of Q&A! Can you break this up into single questions, please? It isn't necessary to throw the quantum mechanics textbook at us when asking a question, the people who can give the best answers know how it works. Why don't we start with the one or two things that occupy your mind the most and go from there? Is it the molecular bonding?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry if this came across as a QM textbook. What I wrote is just a description of what I think is going on. I developed these thoughts over the last day, but I'm not sure if they're all true. And yes, it's the molecular bonding that troubles me most.

Comment: Yeah, too many questions. Or actually, I would say too many _statements_ since most of these aren't really questions. I've put the post on hold for now, but if you narrow it down to just one question (or perhaps a set of _very_ closely related questions) and really ask that question properly, it can certainly be reopened. Asking properly will involve something like stating the thing you believe to be true, why you think it might not be true, and outlining what research you've done to try to figure it out one way or another.

Comment: well, what do you mean by essential? :)

Comment: My simple logic is this. There are four forces in nature. What keeps atoms together in a molecule is not gravity, not strong or weak nuclear forces. Then it must be electromagnetic forces.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments this is indeed a big chunk of statements and it might get a little vague. What I interpret your question to be is how to calculate the potential $V(x)$ (specifically the electrostatic forces) between quantum systems.

Indeed the potential energy $V(x)\vert\psi\rangle$ is calculated in a similar fashion to classical mechanics. Let's take the hydrogen electron in the ground state (which has been solved analytically).

We may take the electron to be in a stationary state. The time-independent Schrödinger equation (TISE) states that

$$\hat{H}\vert\psi\rangle=-\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2\mu}\frac{\partial^{2}\psi}{\partial x^{2}}+V(x)\vert\psi\rangle=E\vert\psi\rangle$$

In the classical two-body system with masses $m_{1},m_{2}$, the *reduced mass* (something like the 'overall mass' of the system) is given by $\mu=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{m_{1}}+\frac{1}{m_{2}}}=\frac{m_{1}m_{2}}{m_{1}+m_{2}}$, and the electrostatic potential energy between the proton and electron is the standard formula $E_{\mathrm{electrostatic}}=-\frac{q^{2}}{4\pi\varepsilon_{0}\vert r\vert}$.

There you have it! A formulation of the TISE for a hydrogen-1 electron:

$$\hat{H}\vert\psi\rangle=-\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2\mu}\frac{\partial^{2}\psi}{\partial x^{2}}-\frac{q^{2}\vert\psi\rangle}{4\pi\varepsilon_{0}\vert r\vert}=E\vert\psi\rangle$$